# Jquery - Delete Row with criteria as a Textbox Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table. First column is Textbox type number. And other columns are just plain text.

I want to delete the row which Textbox value matches with the value which i get in a variable.

For e.g. If i have a value say 6 in a variable, I want to delete the row which has Textbox value as 6.

How to find the row with Textbox type as number & with a predefined value say 6 & then delete that row from table.

I tried :-

```
$('#tblField tr').eq(6).remove();
```

My Table :-

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tblFields">
<tboby>
<tr><td><input type="number" value="20" class="form-control" 

onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)"></td>
<td>ANNUAL PF</td>
<td><input type="text" value="ANNUAL PF" class="displayname form-control"></td><td><input type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
<td style="display:none">ANPF</td>
<td style="display:none">1</td>
</tr>
.....
.....
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle out - https://jsfiddle.net/nfvamrdx/

Html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type ="number" class="txtId" value="3"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type ="text" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type ="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type ="number" class="txtId" value="6"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type ="text" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type ="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type ="number" class="txtId" value="7"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type ="text" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type ="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#btnRemove').click(function(){

var valueToBeRemoved = $('#txtIdToRemove').val();
    $('.txtId[value='+valueToBeRemoved+']').parents('tr').remove();
});
});
```

```
$('#tblField tr input[type="number"][value=' + valueToBeRemoved + ']').parents('tr').remove();
```

Comment: Thankx friend...Works perfectly..!

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method to filter out the `tr` and remove the filtered element by using **[`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)** method.

```
var val = 'your value';

//get all tr and filter
$('tr').filter(function(){
  // get all input tag inside and get element with variable value 
  return $('td input',this).filter(function(){ 
     return this.value == val; 
  }).length;
  // remove the filtered row
}).remove();
```

---

If the value is static and initialized as the attribute then you can use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** along with **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** pseudo-class selector.

```
var val = 'your value';

// get tr contains input elemnt with certain value and remove
$('tr:has(td input[value="' + val + '"])').remove();
```

Comment: I am using like this :- `jq('#tblFields tr').filter(function () {
                    jq('td:first input', this).val() == CurrentOrder;
                }).remove();`

Comment: The table row is not getting removed...!

Comment: Yes...the table has multiple rows...and every rows first column is textbox type number

Comment: Thanks for Help Friend..!

Comment: @Anup : glad to help :)